# Unable to install nodered-contrib-firebase-storage

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-storage, node-red

I am unable to install the Node-RED module named "node-red-contrib-firebase-storage".

So far, I tried on these machines:

- Raspberry PI 3B, with Raspbian Buster
- Raspberry PI 3B, with Ubuntu Core
- Laptop PC, with Ubuntu 19.04

both via Node-Red menu "Manage Palette..." and via command line:

```
npm install node-red-contrib-firebase-storage
```

In all the above combinations, installation fails and the below log is shown.

My main understanding (also reading here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2830) of the root cause is the version *1.10.1* of the dependency **grpc** that the package is trying to install.

Indeed, if I do `npm install grpc`, a different (1.24.2) version of the grpc package is installed, and with no errors.

Did anyone succeed installing this package?
May anyone help me understanding how to install this Node-RED module?

This is the log:

```
2019-11-25T18:34:07.666Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --save --save-prefix="~" --production node-red-contrib-firebase-storage@1.1.0
2019-11-25T18:34:30.776Z [err] npm
2019-11-25T18:34:30.776Z [err]  WARN deprecated core-js@2.5.5: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
2019-11-25T18:34:48.500Z [out] 
2019-11-25T18:34:48.500Z [out] > grpc@1.10.1 install /root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc
2019-11-25T18:34:48.500Z [out] > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
2019-11-25T18:34:48.500Z [out] 
2019-11-25T18:35:02.084Z [err] node-pre-gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:02.084Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:02.085Z [err] Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc.tar.gz 
2019-11-25T18:35:02.086Z [err] node-pre-gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:02.086Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:02.086Z [err] Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
2019-11-25T18:35:02.132Z [err] node-pre-gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:02.132Z [err]  ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
2019-11-25T18:35:02.133Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:02.133Z [err]  Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
2019-11-25T18:35:02.133Z [err]  
2019-11-25T18:35:05.452Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.453Z [err]  WARN 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.454Z [err] install got an error, rolling back install
2019-11-25T18:35:05.458Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.459Z [err]  
2019-11-25T18:35:05.459Z [err] WARN install got an error, rolling back install
2019-11-25T18:35:05.481Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.481Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.482Z [err] configure error 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.482Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.482Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.483Z [err] stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown '/root/snap/node-red/525/.node-gyp/10.16.3'
2019-11-25T18:35:05.484Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.484Z [err]  ERR! System
2019-11-25T18:35:05.484Z [err]  Linux 4.15.0-1049-raspi2
2019-11-25T18:35:05.485Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.485Z [err]  ERR! command
2019-11-25T18:35:05.486Z [err]  "/snap/node-red/525/bin/node" "/snap/node-red/525/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc"
2019-11-25T18:35:05.486Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.486Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.486Z [err] cwd /root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc
2019-11-25T18:35:05.486Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.487Z [err]  ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:05.487Z [err]  node -v v10.16.3
2019-11-25T18:35:05.487Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.487Z [err]  ERR! node-gyp -v
2019-11-25T18:35:05.487Z [err]  v3.8.0
2019-11-25T18:35:05.487Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.488Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.488Z [err] not ok 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.492Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.492Z [err]  ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:05.493Z [err]  configure error
2019-11-25T18:35:05.493Z [err]  
2019-11-25T18:35:05.494Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.494Z [err]  ERR! stack
2019-11-25T18:35:05.495Z [err]  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown '/root/snap/node-red/525/.node-gyp/10.16.3'
2019-11-25T18:35:05.496Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.496Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.496Z [err] System Linux 4.15.0-1049-raspi2
2019-11-25T18:35:05.497Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.497Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.497Z [err] command "/snap/node-red/525/bin/node" "/snap/node-red/525/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc"
2019-11-25T18:35:05.498Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.498Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.498Z [err] cwd /root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc
2019-11-25T18:35:05.498Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.498Z [err]  ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:05.499Z [err]  
2019-11-25T18:35:05.499Z [err] node -v
2019-11-25T18:35:05.499Z [err]  v10.16.3
2019-11-25T18:35:05.499Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.499Z [err]  ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:05.499Z [err]  
2019-11-25T18:35:05.500Z [err] node-gyp -v
2019-11-25T18:35:05.500Z [err]  v3.8.0
2019-11-25T18:35:05.500Z [err] gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.501Z [err]  
2019-11-25T18:35:05.501Z [err] ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.501Z [err] not ok 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.502Z [err] node-pre-gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.506Z [err]  ERR! build error 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.506Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/snap/node-red/525/bin/node /snap/node-red/525/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc' (1)
2019-11-25T18:35:05.506Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
2019-11-25T18:35:05.506Z [err] node-pre-gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.506Z [err]  ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-11-25T18:35:05.506Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:05.507Z [err]  stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
2019-11-25T18:35:05.507Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
2019-11-25T18:35:05.510Z [err] node-pre-gyp
2019-11-25T18:35:05.511Z [err]  ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1049-raspi2
2019-11-25T18:35:05.511Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/snap/node-red/525/bin/node" "/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
2019-11-25T18:35:05.511Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:05.512Z [err]  cwd /root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc
2019-11-25T18:35:05.512Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
2019-11-25T18:35:05.513Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
2019-11-25T18:35:05.513Z [err] node-pre-gyp ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.514Z [err] not ok 
2019-11-25T18:35:05.515Z [out] Failed to execute '/snap/node-red/525/bin/node /snap/node-red/525/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/root/snap/node-red/525/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-arm-glibc' (1)
2019-11-25T18:35:07.757Z [err] npm
2019-11-25T18:35:07.757Z [err]  ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-25T18:35:07.758Z [err] npm
2019-11-25T18:35:07.758Z [err]  ERR! errno
2019-11-25T18:35:07.758Z [err]  1
2019-11-25T18:35:07.762Z [err] npm
2019-11-25T18:35:07.763Z [err]  ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
2019-11-25T18:35:07.763Z [err] npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-11-25T18:35:07.763Z [err] npm
2019-11-25T18:35:07.763Z [err]  ERR! 
2019-11-25T18:35:07.764Z [err] npm ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:07.764Z [err]  Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
2019-11-25T18:35:07.764Z [err] npm
2019-11-25T18:35:07.764Z [err]  ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:07.764Z [err]  This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-11-25T18:35:07.885Z [err] 
2019-11-25T18:35:07.885Z [err] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-11-25T18:35:07.886Z [err] npm ERR!
2019-11-25T18:35:07.886Z [err]      /root/snap/node-red/525/.npm/_logs/2019-11-25T18_35_07_828Z-debug.log
2019-11-25T18:35:07.930Z rc=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Node 10 (grpc 1.10 does not support Node 10) - and the 1.1.0 version of `nodered-contrib-firebase-storage` package uses `firebase@4.13.1` - which requires `grpc 1.10`.

You can use 1.2.0 version of this package - it has firebase dependency version bumped up.

Other workaround is to use older version of Node.